# rootKey is null inside PreferenceFragmentCompat.onCreatePreferences()

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferencefragment

I'm extending [PreferenceFragmentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat) from Android's support library. The `onCreatePreferences()` method gives me a `rootKey`, which is a nullable string. The documentation says this about the parameter:

> **rootKey** - If non-null, this preference fragment should be rooted at the PreferenceScreen with this key.

In my preferences xml, I've set the `android:key` property:

```
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="prefs_behavior">
...
```

But the `rootKey` value given to me in `onCreatePreferences()` is still null.

There's also a nullable string that I need to provide to `setPreferencesFromResource`:

> **key** - The preference key of the PreferenceScreen to use as the root of the preference hierarchy, or null to use the root PreferenceScreen.

I don't know whether it's safe to provide null to `setPreferencesFromResource()` just because `onCreatePreferences()` gave me null. The examples I've found suggest that you normally use `rootKey` as `key`, but my fragment has some non-standard behavior, and I'm trying to pin down a crash bug. **Why is rootKey null in my case, and what is the correct value for the key parameter of setPreferencesFromResource?**

Comment: Same question; why is rootkey null?

Comment: Is rootKey used to define the shared preference file?